# Any algorithm/approach to 'simulate' a cyclic graph over time?

Tags: algorithm, graph, linear-algebra, graph-algorithm

I don't know if something like this is even possible or where to look for something that could help address the same - hence the question for seeking some pointers.

Here is my situation: I have a matrix representation of a graph of activities. Each entry in the matrix indicates the relative impact of an activity on the other i.e., (There are 'n' activities in the 'system'. The matrix is just an 'n x n' representation of these activities and the entries imply relative impact)

- 0 (no impact) 1, 2, 3 (low, medium, high) 'positive' impact i.e., they positively (add) contribute to the activity
- Negative numbers: -1, -2, -3 imply a 'negative' impact i.e., they negatively (subtract) contribute

(The numbers are informational, could be any numbers really but just simplified it to 0-3).

Now given this matrix I'll have a description of a graph. What I'd like to do is to 'simulate' the graph over time i.e., starting at time `t=0` I'd like to be able to simulate the working of the 'system' over time. I'll have cycles in the graph for sure (very likely) and thus a time-step based simulation would be apt here.

I am not aware of anything in that I could use to help me understand the effects over time for a cyclic graph. I am aware of ONLY one such solution i.e., to use System Dynamics and convert this graph into stock/flow diagram and then simulate it to get what I want. Effectively the graph (above) is then a causal-loop diagram.

Issue: I'd really like to go from the matrix representation to a simulate-able system without forcing someone to understand system dynamics (basically do something in the background).

The question is: Is System Dynamics the only way to achieve what I'm looking for? How should I go about systematically converting any arbitrary matrix representation of graph into a system dynamic model?

If NOT system dynamics, then what other approaches should I look at to solve such a problem? Algorithm names with corresponding pointers for reference would be appreciated!

An example representation of a graph:

Say I have the following matrix of 3 activities:
Rows: Nodes that are 'cause' (outgoing arrows)
Columns: Nodes being 'affected' (incoming arrows)

```
__| A | B | C |
A | - | 3 | 2 |
B | 1 | - |-2 |
C |-1 | 0 | - |
```

If I 'start' the graph (simulation) with 10 units for A I'd like to see how the system plays out over time given the relative impacts in the matrix representation.

**UPDATE:** The 'simulation' would be in a series of time steps i.e., at time t=0 the node A would have the value of 10 and B would either multiply by 3 or add 3 depending on how someone would want to specify the 'impact'. The accumulated values of the nodes over time could be plotted on a graph to show the trend of how the value progresses.

Comment: Please explain more about the "simulation" that this matrix defines. As you've described it, it seems that something as simple as repeated matrix multiplication would do the job, or any of several methods for solving systems of differential equations.

Comment: @user57368 - Could you please elaborate more on repeated matrix multiplication and 'which' of the several methods for solving systems of differential equations could/would/should I use. Pointers??

Comment: @Nupul: What user57368 meant was that if you defined more precisely what you do with the matrix then it might be possible to find a traditional problem to match it. Currently the "simulation" and "activities" and "impacts" are a tad to informal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been several attempts to do this, with various origins in the cybernetics and system dynamics literature, without much success.

Basically the problem is that your matrix, while it may contain a lot of insight and have useful applications for group process, falls short of the degree of specification that one needs to actually simulate a dynamic system.

The matrix identifies the feedback loops that exist in your system, but to relate that structure to behavior, you also need to specify phase and gain relationships around those loops (i.e., identify the stocks and the slope of each relationship, which may be nonlinear). Without doing this, there's simply no way to establish which loops are dominant drivers of the behavior.

You might be able to get some further insight out of your matrix through graph theoretic approaches to identifying and visualizing important features, but unfortunately there's no escaping the model-building process if you want to simulate.

Comment: Good point. My intention is to make this process as easy as possible without a steep learning curve involved with the model building process, so that it could be done/created by 'business' people too rather than require someone with a modeling expertise...I'm still trying to crack it though. Hence the question to gain some directions from the community

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you are looking for [Markov chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain).

Let *G* be a system of states.

[image]

The probability of the system transferring from one state to another is given by the matrix *T*.

[image]f

After *n* transferences, the probability of the system transferring from one state to another is given by *T<sub>n</sub>*.

[image]
For example, after 3 transferences:

[image]
This matrix represents:

- Given the system is in A, it has a

  - 32.4% chance of remaining at A
  - 31.2% chance of transferring to B
  - 36.4% chance of transferring to C
- etcetera for B and C

I would attempt to apply this to your situation for you, but I do not really understand it.
If you are to use Markov chains, you must establish a probability of the system transferring.
Note that, because this is "chance of system being at a given node", you can apply it to a population of systems.
For example: After *n* transferences, X.XX% of the population will be at *Y*.

Comment: Could a user with more reputation edit my answer with the images embedded, please.
As a new user, I'm not allowed to post many images or hyperlinks.

Comment: @Deco: Good suggestion. I'm not sure if probability of 'transfer' would be what I'm looking for but nevertheless I'll explore the option of Markov Chains and see if that would help me in some way...not sure as of yet though...